# Which activation function is better to a 1-dimensional time series in a LSTM model?

Tags: neural-networks, lstm

I am experimenting with a LSTM model (I have normalized the data) until now the 'sigmoid' performs better than others. How can I justify/interpret it?

Answer (score 1):

The sigmoid activation is a key part of the architecture because it is part of the implementation the constant error carousel. This is the key feature of the LSTM that hedges against degenerate behaviors common in vanilla RNNs. See "Long Short-Term Memory", Sepp Hochreiter and Jürgen Schmidhuber *Neural Computation* Volume 9 Issue 8, November 15, 1997.